# Is it better to encrypt to an untrusted key or not to encrypt at all?

Tags: pgp

If a public PGP key can be retrieved, but there is no known path of trust from the sender to the receiver: Is is better to encrypt the message using the key on spec or to not encrypt at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the key is completely untrustworthy to the point that anyone can decrypt the message, then it can't be any less secure (*technically*) than unencrypted.

The main risk is psychological, in that you may come to trust the untrusted key.

Answer (score 0):

You should always encrypt -- it can't be less secure than unencrypted anyway.

Even if there is no known path from sender to receiver, and even if you're afraid of a MiTM attack -- it's still better to encrypt that leave it in the clear.

However, the more important question is whether to send the message at all, or how you could create a chain of trust with the receiver/sender, rather than if you think encrypting is better than leaving it in the clear.